# Customized diamond shape using while loop & nested for-loop (java)

Tags: java, loops, shapes, spacing

My program compiles and runs but my spacing for "Enter a size..." is incorrect. Would like some help with spacing, and System.out.println formatting in the loop for my program to have proper spacing as intended.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintCustomizedDiamond {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a letter:");
    char ch = s.next().charAt(0);
    int a = 0, b, c, d;
    d = a - 1;
    while (a < 6 || a % 2 == 1) { 
        System.out.print("Enter a size (even number no less than 6): ");
        a = s.nextInt();
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("");
      }
        else {
          System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    d = (a / 2) - 1;
    for (b = 2; b <= a; b = b + 2) {
      for (c = 0; c < d; c++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (c = 0; c < b; c++) {
        System.out.print(ch);
      }
      d = d - 1;
      System.out.println();
    }
    d = 0;
    for (b = a; b >= 2; b = b -2) {
      for (c = d; c > 0; c--)
      {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (c = 0; c < b; c++)
      {
        System.out.print(ch);
      }
      d = d + 1;
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: what is input and output you want

Comment: input is using user specified characters and size, where the size should be an even number greater than or equal to 6. Ex: Enter a letter: A
  Enter a size (even number no less than 6): 5
  Enter a size (even number no less than 6): 9
  Enter a size (even number no less than 6): 6
      AA
    AAAA
  AAAAAA
  AAAAAA 
    AAAA
      AA        "All Enter..." statements should be all in one line as well.

Comment: sorry, can you add it to the question section